# How to go about solving this question on positive semi-definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

How to go about solving this question? I'm stuck and can't proceed. Appreciate any help.
[image: Check question here]

Comment: That is false.. There's a 2x2 counterexample

Comment: What is it? Pls post it here bro.

Comment: I tried for hours but unable to think of any counterexamples. Just proof checking, the sum of the elements of a PSD matrix is always >= 0. And A=A* and its eigenvalues are non-negative if A is PSD. Does your example satisfy these?

Comment: uh, sorry, the counterexample I have in mind holds only if all entries are real

Comment: But if it works for complex numbers, it should work for real numbers too right?

Comment: I was thinking both $A,B$ were real

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But no probs, I got my doubt resolved. Thx for spending time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

When both $A$ and $B$ are PSD, $(B^T)^{1/2}A(B^T)^{1/2}$ is also PSD. Hence
$$
\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}b_{ij}=\operatorname{tr}(AB^T)=\operatorname{tr}\left((B^T)^{1/2}A(B^T)^{1/2}\right)\ge0.
$$
Conversely, if $A$ is not PSD, then there exists a vector $v$ such that $v^\ast Av$ is not real nonnegative. Thus $\operatorname{tr}(AB^T)=v^\ast Av$ is not real nonnegative for the PSD matrix $B=(vv^\ast)^T$.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Thanks a lot. Also, can you shed some light on how you came about this method of solving the question?

Comment: @Adithya52 The first step is to try to formulate the problem in terms of more high-level objects, such as matrices or linear transformations.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean. Appreciate the help.